# Scrollable List Component from Material-UI in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How to make the List component (see https://material-ui.com/components/lists/) fixed-size and scrollable?
Every time I add a new ListItem the List expands, however I would like to be able to scroll through it if content gets bigger than the container.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

I just found out that you can add properties. 'maxHeight' and 'overflow' are the ones I was needing to solve my problem.
For example for a List in a Paper container:

```
<Paper style={{maxHeight: 200, overflow: 'auto'}}>
  <List>
   ...
  </List>
</Paper>
```

Answer (score 38):

This works if you want the list to fill all height of the container:

```
<List style={{maxHeight: '100%', overflow: 'auto'}} />
```

Comment: This only works if the parent element also has a height defined which material components tend not to do

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was looking for a way to make the content inside a `<Card />` to be scrollable, in case the amount of text was larger than the `maxHeight` of the card.

This worked perfectly for me:

```
<Card sx={{ minHeight: '60vh', overflow: 'auto' }}></Card>
```